# How can an Applet call a method in a different frame (from the same web site)?

Tags: java, javascript, frames, liveconnect

Given an Applet in one frame in a multi-frame web application where all frames are loaded from the same web server, how can that Applet invoke JavaScript methods in other frames?  I tried something like this:

```
jsobject.call("parent.otherFrame.methodToCall", new String[] {"argument"});
```

and I get a complaint that the function does not exist.  However, if I invoke it like this:

```
jsobject.eval("parent.otherFrame.methodToCall('argument')");
```

then it works.  I'm trying to avoid use of `eval`.  Is calling code via `call` in a different frame from an Applet something that is likely to have different behavior in each browser and JVM combination?  Is `eval` safer as it is evaluated in the JavaScript engine rather than partly on the Applet side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent code without eval is probably something like this:

```
jsobject = (JSObject)jsobject.getMember("parent");
jsobject = (JSObject)jsobject.getMember("otherFrame");
jsobject.call("methodToCall", new String[] {"hello!"});
```

Comment: While the other answer was also good, this answer is closer to the intent of my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My (limited) experience with a combination of Java applets, JavaScript and (the dreaded) frames, is that it is best to:

- Include a script in the page/frame with the applet in it.  Define a function intended to be called with 0 or more arguments (one of which might be the name of the target frame).
- Call the function from the applet.
- Let the JavaScript do the heavy lifting of finding the correct frame & doing whatever needs to be done.

This has a number of advantages.

- It is easier to debug JS using the (for example) FF error console, than using the Java console.
- JS can be updated more quickly and easily.
- Each language encodes what it is good at doing.  You can go into a Java editor to see the Java nicely formatted, and a JS editor to see the JS nicely formatted.  As opposed to trying to read "JS written in Java" - a scarey experience.
- When you ask for help on getting the script working, you have a neat example that the JS gurus can easily read!